# disable items showing up in windows 10 timeline

Tags: winapi, windows-10, timeline, windows-shell

I have a win32 text editor app. Every file that opens in it is automatically added to the Windows 10 timeline. The problem is that these entries in the timeline are useless because they don't actually work (i.e., you can't click on them to re-open the file in my editor), and instead of the editor app name the timeline shows the AppUserModelID instead.

Is there an API that I can call to prevent Windows from adding the files opened in my editor to the timeline? Or maybe an entry in the apps manifest?

Note that I'm setting the [AppUserModelID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-setcurrentprocessexplicitappusermodelid) to control the Jumplist feature, which I'd like to keep. I just don't want the files to show up in the timeline.
Also it seems that only files added to the recent docs with [SHAddToRecentDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shaddtorecentdocs) show up.

Or maybe there's a way to get the entries in the timeline to work properly (i.e., when clicked open them in my editor, and have the app name show up properly).

update: [image: screenshot of my timeline]

Comment: *"Or maybe there's a way to get the entries in the timeline to work properly"* - Seeing that this feature appears to work for everyone except your application, I'd assume that this is indeed possible. Though we cannot see your [mcve] and consequently cannot know, what your issue is. Maybe want to read [ask].

Comment: how would I create an example if I don't even know what Windows considers to add something to the timeline? I'm not adding it myself there, so there's no code example I can provide.

Comment: [Application Engagement in Windows Timeline with User Activities](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/12/19/application-engagement-windows-timeline-user-activities/).

Comment: I've read that. But I'm not adding anything myself to the timeline. Windows does this itself, but apparently not properly.

Comment: @Stefan I am trying to find the official document for this, however failed. Is it possible to remove any sensitive code and share the sample you were developing? If not, to resolve this issue, you may need to contact Microsoft support.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT I've tried, but in my test project it does not happen. What I could figure out this far: you have make the app the default for at least one file type, and I think the app needs to be added to the task bar at least once. The project this happens is BowPad: https://github.com/stefankueng/BowPad - clone it recursively. But the app needs to be installed first - just building won't work because it requires some registry keys to be present.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for this info, however the timeline works for me for the BowPad app when I try to open it from **Now**, can you help confirm if it works for you? Or the issue only occurred for open the file from a long time-line like **Yesterday**?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Strange it works for you. It doesn't work for me independent on how long ago from the timeline I click on an entry. But I noticed that the shell keeps some kind of cache because when I changed the appID for testing, it somehow still had the old one. Is there a way to clear this cache? I first thought that maybe I had some test-registry entries lying around which caused this, but then I noticed the same problem on my office PC where I never built BP but used the msi only.

Comment: @Stefan I am trying to confirm with my college to see if there is anyway to clear that cache. BTW, which version you were testing? Currently it was tested on Version 2004(OS Build 19041.208) on my side

Comment: @Stefan Where did you change the AppID? In the application coder or the shortcut used to start the application? And does clearing the activity history via Windows Settings->Privacy->Activity History fix this issue?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT I'm currently on OS Build 19042.450, but in the office I'm on the same as you. The AppID is set in code on startup, but also when setting up the jumplist. Is it maybe possible to make the documents public which explain why files are added to the timeline and under what circumstances? I've cleared the history, but as soon as I open a file in BP it shows up again in the timeline and clicks on it don't work.